# Create react app PWA manifest.json not being cached

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm building a React app using create-react-app and I used the following command to make it from the beginning a PWA.

```js
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

After building my app, going to the browser developer tools, and look into the cache, I noticed all my images and files are cached but not my **manifest.json**. I can see my **manifest.json** being in the app since I can look at it in the dev tools and I can install the app on my computer. The problem comes when I go offline, the **manifest.json** is not found because it's not cached.

- How can I cache my manifest.json?
- Why my manifest.json isn't cached as default?

This is the error I see in my console when I serve the app offline:

> GET http://localhost:5000/manifest.json net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
> 200

[image]

Service Worker generated by CRA;

````js
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

clientsClaim();

// Precache all of the assets generated by your build process.
// Their URLs are injected into the manifest variable below.
// This variable must be present somewhere in your service worker file,
// even if you decide not to use precaching. See https://cra.link/PWA
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// Set up App Shell-style routing, so that all navigation requests
// are fulfilled with your index.html shell. Learn more at
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    } // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.

    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    } // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains // a file extension, skip.

    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    } // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.

    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'), // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

// This allows the web app to trigger skipWaiting via
// registration.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'})
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});```
````

Comment: how we can help without code? first share your service-worker... maybe you made mistake to set dir and path...

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh if you have used CRA and run the command I mentioned, the service worker is auto-generated using workbox I didn't touch the service worker at all. So I assume all the CRA that are made PWAs don't cache de manifest.json

Comment: Is it an issue that the manifest isn't cached?

Comment: Based on the conversation I'm having with Google developer experts, Microsoft devs and more it should be cached https://twitter.com/jeffposnick/status/1446099748302344195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caching of `manifest.json` in PWAs presents a unique challenge due to its location in the `public/` folder of PWA templates. As it resides outside the src folder, conventional approaches like `InjectManifest` may not pick it up.

For a detailed discussion on this issue, refer to these threads:

1. [Thread on Twitter](https://x.com/webmaxru/status/1446049325570830344?s=20)
2. [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11517#issuecomment-939044029)

As noted in the GitHub thread, adding `manifest.json` to `self.__WB_MANIFEST` and precaching it doesn't offer a straightforward solution.

One approach is to treat `manifest.json` as any other [static resource](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-recipes#static_resources_cache) and apply the `StaleWhileRevalidate` strategy. To do so, add manifest.json criteria  to the latest `registerRoute`:

```js
// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => {
    const isPng = url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png');
    const isManifestJson = url.pathname === '/manifest.json';
    return isPng || isManifestJson;
  },  
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size,
      // the least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);
```